# Symmetric binary tree called recursively

Tags: java, c#, .net, recursion

In the below recursive function **FindAllNodes** , will the condition in return **t1.data == t2.dat**a be called every node multiple times? Because if the current node is "2" then recursively the control goes to the child nodes and once again comes back to "2" . So will the if condition be called multiple times for the same node? I have a bit of confusion in understanding recursive functions when it involves multiple recursions along with conditions in the return statement

```
 public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node left, right;
        public int level;

        public Node(int item)
        {
            data = item;
            left = right = null;
            level = 0;
        }
    }
    public class BinaryTree
    {
        // Root of the Binary Tree
        Node root;

        public bool FindAllNodes(Node t1, Node t2)
        {
            if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
            if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;
            
            return (t1.data == t2.data)
                && FindAllNodes(t1.right, t2.left)
                && FindAllNodes(t2.left, t2.right);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
            tree.root = new Node(1);
            tree.root.left = new Node(2);
            tree.root.right = new Node(2);
            tree.root.left.left = new Node(3);
            tree.root.left.right = new Node(4);
            tree.root.right.left = new Node(4);
            tree.root.right.right = new Node(3);

            bool isSymmetric = tree.FindAllNodes(tree.root, tree.root);

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you also share BinaryTree and Node class?

Comment: Should it be return (t1.data == t2.data)
                && FindAllNodes(t1.left, t2.left)
                && FindAllNodes(t2.right, t2.right);?

Comment: @Izikon no, they is no problem with the logic

Answer (score 0):

yes you have...

```
 public bool FindAllNodes(Node t1, Node t2)
    {
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
        if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;
        return (t1.data == t2.data)
            && FindAllNodes(t1.right, t2.right)
            && FindAllNodes(t1.left, t2.left);
    }
```

checked it few times